# Laravel - Check when account is created

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

On a website I'm building, accounts are automatically generated when a visitor loads the page. When an account gets created,  the new user will be asked to choose a username by creating a modal window and when the user submits the new username, the data will be sent back to the server and the modal will close.

So the only problem now is that I'm not sure how to call this modal window, only when the new account is generated. Right now it shows up every-time a page reload happens, but what should happen is when only after the account is generated.

So this should be called when the account is made, but only when that happens:

```
$('#i-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

When the account is created, this happens. Request is sent to `/createUser`

UserController:

```
public function createUser()
{

    $newUser = new User;

    $newUser->username = 'user-'.Helpers::randomLowerCase(4);

    $newUser->save();
    // Check if user isn't logged in yet
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        Auth::login($newUser);
    } else {
       // ...
    }
    // Return the user home
    return Redirect::action('HomeController@showHome');
}
```

So how should I do this and only call `$('#i-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');` when after the account is created?

Comment: suppose there are two persons that uses the computer. how will you distinguish between them?

Comment: You should look into making an ajax call to create the user.

Comment: Are you sure this is a pattern you want to use? I see a lot of potential for abuse here. Namely, open in Incognito (or the equivalent), load your page, create a username, close incognito, and repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be to store in `http session` the username that is entered by the user and probably also automatically log in the user to the system. Then if the page reloads, the `UserController` checks in session to see if a username has been stored or if the user is logged in. Based on the outcome the modal is shown or not.

Thus, when the page is first loaded you could do the following steps (followed by untested code as example of where each part of code could be placed),

**1.** Check the session (php http session , e.g.`session_start();if(isset($_SESSION[$username])){..`) to see if a username exists or `Auth::check()`.

**php**

```
Route::get('checkUser', 'UserController@checkUser');
Route::get('createUser/{username}', 'UserController@createUser');
class UserController extends BaseController {
public function checkUser(){
      session_start();
      if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){/*or use something like Auth::check()*/
        return Response::json(array('exists' => 'true'));
/*or redirect e.g.  return Redirect::action('HomeController@showHome');*/
/*or render a view e.g. return View::make('user.page', array('username' => $username));*/
          }else{
            return Response::json(array('exists' => 'false'));
          }
    }
    ....
```

**1.1** If it exists, do not execute the js code that shows a foundation modal and welcome user.

**1.2** If it does not exist, execute the js code and show the modal window asking the user to log in.

**js** (*or entered from your php code via views, e.g. from a controller return View::make('user.page', array('username' => $username));*)

```
$.ajax({
       url: "checkUser"
        success: function(data) { 
            if(!data.exists) {
                $('#i-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
            }else{
                /*set any content e.g. welcome user*/
            }
        }
    });
```

**1.2.1** If the user enters the existing username or if a new one is generated, log in the user and store the username in the session.

**php**

```
....
Route::get('createUser/{username}', 'UserController@createUser');

class UserController extends BaseController {
....
/*your code slightly modified*/
  public function createUser($username)
{

  // Check if user isn't logged in yet
  if (!Auth::check()/*&& if persistence is used, which is best to actually use it to persist usernames, check if the username is available*/) {

     $newUser = new User;

     //$newUser->username = 'user-'.Helpers::randomLowerCase(4);
     $newUser->username=$username;

     $newUser->save();

     Auth::login($newUser);
  } else {
     return Response::json(array('created' => 'false'));
   /* or  return Redirect::action('HomeController@loginFailed');*/
  }

  // Return the user home
  return Redirect::action('HomeController@showHome');
}
....
```

**js**

```
$.ajax({
           url: "createUser",
           data:{usernae:the_username_from_modal}
            success: function(data) { 
                if(!data.created) {
                    /*if the redirection is not handled by the controller, handle the failed login/registration of existing username*/
                }
            }
        });
```

Also in your code you should probably store the username, to a persistent layer, in order to check for existing usernames, allow users to use their existing usernames and restore/retrieve any kind of state or data you may also be persisting within your app.

Answer (score 4):

I would use AJAX to check for the account.  When the document is done loading, fire off a request which will check to make sure that the account is fully setup with a username.  If there isn't, then you can pop the modal, which I'm assuming you already have setup.

For this example, I'm creating an AjaxController which would be where you put all your ajax call logic, but these functions can go anywhere.  Just make sure to change the route accordingly.  Be aware that this code is largely untested.

```
// Route
Route::post('ajax/checkUserAccount', array('uses' => 'AjaxController@checkUserAccountExists', as 'ajax.checkUserAccount');

// Controller
AjaxController extends BaseController {
    public function checkUserAccountExists {
        // Do user account check logic here.  This is just an example as I'm not sure how you plan on handling this or what variables are set when someone creates an account
        $userCount = DB::table('users')->where('username', Input::get('username'))->count();
        if($userCount > 0) { 
            return Response::json(array('member' => 'true'));
        } else {
            return Response::json(array('member' => 'false'));
        }
    }
}

// jQuery AJAX 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST"
        , url: "{{ URL::route('ajax.checkUserAccount') }}"
        success: function(data) { 
            if(data.member === false) {
                $('#i-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open'); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This makes no sense whatsoever. Why would you create an account automatically when a page loads? You don't know who loaded the page or why or whether they are eligible to create an account. Your create account modal should not open unless the user clicks a "create account" link or performs an equivalent call to action. Furthermore, the account should not actually be created until the form data submitted by the modal has been sucecssfully validated on the back end.

The form displayed in this modal should use JavaScript validation on the front end. This will save the user the trouble of of waiting until the data has been posted to find out that they did not properly complete the form. You can further enhance the UX by incorporating Ajax into the frontend validation.  For example, the onblur event of the user name input could trigger a method that queries the DB and checks if the user name is available. You could have a similar Ajax method for the email input which would checks if the email address is already registered. You can do all of this with the stock jQuery validation plugin.

Please note that the frontend validation is merely a convenience for the user. You will still need to validate the data on the server side since client-side JS can easily be bypassed by a user with malicious intent.

Answer (score -2):

I think a better solution would be to include a javascript variable `User` in the header of the HTML Document.

To do this, you can create a global variable that's shared with all views by using

```
View::share('user', $current_user);
```

Then in your view file in the `<head>` you can add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var User = {{ $user->toJson() }}</script>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
if (User.id == 0)
    $('#i-modal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

Comment: Not great in the way of security. You really want to keep that stuff server-side.

Comment: @Steve you can guard certain user data in the user model, or, maybe just output a boolean.